# How to fix console return of malloc(): memory corruption (fast)

Tags: c, memory-management

When I ran a program, my console output showed the following:
**malloc(): memory corruption (fast)** and was followed by what seemed like an address in memory. I have narrowed it down to a few functions, but I feel that I free all memory that I allocate properly.

The following function takes a string representing a file name.

```
void readAndProcessFile(char* filename){

    FILE *fileptr;
    char* word = malloc(32*sizeof(char));

    fileptr = fopen(filename, "r");

    while(fscanf(fileptr,"%s",word) != EOF){
        processWord(word);
    }

    fclose(fileptr);
    free(word);
}
```

This function takes a word, removes any non-alphabetic characters and changes all letters to uppercase.

```
void processWord(char* text){
    char* processedWord;
    processedWord = trimAndCaps(text);

    if(processedWord != NULL && processedWord[0] != '\0'){
        addWord(processedWord);
    }
    free(processedWord);
}
```

Here's the trim and cap function

```
char* trimAndCaps(char* text)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char currentChar;
    char* rv = malloc(sizeof(text));

    while ((currentChar = text[i++]) != '\0')
    {
        if (isalpha(currentChar))
        {
            rv[j++] = toupper(currentChar);
        }
    }
    rv[j] = '\0';

    return rv;
}
```

And just for good measure here's the addWord function

```
void addWord(char* word)
{
    // check if word is already in list
    struct worddata* currentWord = findWord(word);

    // word is in list
    if(currentWord != NULL)
    {
        incrementCount(currentWord);
    }
    // word is not in list
    else
    {
        currentWord = malloc(sizeof(struct worddata));
        currentWord->count = 1;
        strcpy(currentWord->word, word);
        ll_add(wordList, currentWord, sizeof(struct worddata));
        free(currentWord);
    }
}
```

As you can see, all instances where I manually allocate memory, I free afterwards. This program works when there is a smaller amount of words, but not for larger. My thought process leads me to believe that there is some sort of leak, but when I have few enough words to the point that I can run it, I run the following code:

```
// The following code will print out the final dynamic memory used
struct mallinfo veryend = mallinfo();
fprintf(stderr, "Final Dynamic Memory used : %d\n", veryend.uordblks);
```

And this shows a 0 every time for memory used. What else can cause this? Any direction or fixes are much appreciated.

Comment: The problem is likely that you've written outside the bounds of the allocated space and the `malloc()` system is reporting this.  So it may not be that you're freeing something wrong; it is at least likely that you've misused what was allocated.  Are you on a platform where using [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) is an option.

Comment: `char* rv = malloc(sizeof(text));` --> `char* rv = malloc(strlen(text)+1);`

Comment: Try using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find your problem. You're probably writing out of bounds somewhere, possibly with `strcpy(currentWord->word, word);` depending on your struct definition, and almost certainly after `char* rv = malloc(sizeof(text));`

Comment: It doesn't say you have a memory leak. It says you have a memory corruption. But we can't really help if you don't show all your code. You have admirably tried to explain what **you think** is happening. But by definition you don't know where the problem is so by doing that you may or may not have included the actual root cause. Suggest you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Better still since it looks like you are on Linux, run the swiss army knife of memory debugging - [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line doesn't do what you are hoping to:

```
char* rv = malloc(sizeof(text));
```

It only allocates `4` or`8` bytes or memory depending on the size of pointers on your platform.

You need:

```
char* rv = malloc(strlen(text) + 1);
```